# How to calculate equal distribution of a specific column?

Tags: sql

For example I have a table like this:

```sql
|   id| vals|
|-----|-----|
|    1| 9.88|
|    2| 3.24|
|    3|6.943|
..........
..........
| 1000|4.601|
```

I want to calculate something like this(N vals):

```
|  vals|
|------|
|   0.8|
| 1.649|
| 2.303|
    ...
    ...
|  10.0|
```

The amount of entries between [0, 0.8) = [0.8, 1.649) = [1.649, 2.303) ... = [?, 10.0). And [0, 0.8) + [0.8, 1.649) + [1.649, 2.303) + ... + [?, 10.0) = 1000.

How to implement such a SQL query?

Comment: I have removed those conflicting dbms tags. Put one of them back, the one for the dbms actually used.

Comment: Can you provide complete sample data and the expected results of that sample, not just partials? Makes testing a lot easier.

Comment: @Shawn The sample above is just something I made up. The complete sample is quite large to share/paste here : (

Comment: I *think* I know what you want and how to calculate it, but really need numbers to work with to make sure I'm on the right track.